# Error on sauce labs Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed

Tags: serenity-bdd

Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: WebDriver was unable to create a new instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
WebDriver reported the following message: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed.

While executing the test script in sauce labs getting an error.But when i have run on the same script on the local its working as expected. below is code -

```
webdriver {
   ` webdriver {
          driver = "firefox"
            capabilities {
              pageLoadStrategy = "normal"
              acceptInsecureCerts = true
              unhandledPromptBehavior = "dismiss"
              strictFileInteractability = true

              "moz:firefoxOptions" {
                args = ["-headless"],
                prefs {
                  "javascript.options.showInConsole": false
                },
                log {"level": "info"},
              }
            }
          }`
```